# Extracting text from link in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping

I have a script in python 2.7 that scrapes the table in this page:
http://www.the-numbers.com/movie/budgets/all

I want to extract each of the columns, the problem is that my code doesn't recognize the columns that have links (2nd and 3rd columns).

```
budgeturl = "http://www.the-numbers.com/movie/budgets/all"
s = urllib.urlopen(budgeturl).read()
htmlpage = etree.HTML(s)
htmltable = htmlpage.xpath("//td[@class='data']/text()")
```

With this code htmltable[0] is the rank, htmltable[1] is Production Budget and continues from there onwards. 
From the ones I am missing, I need the text not the link.

Comment: Can you just grab the text without specifying `class='data'`? It looks like the other TDs have no class.

Comment: Not sure how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to amend your xpath since not all `td` elements have `class="data"`.
Try this xpath expression: `//td//text()`.

```
import urllib
from lxml import etree

budgeturl = "http://www.the-numbers.com/movie/budgets/all"
s = urllib.urlopen(budgeturl).read()
htmlpage = etree.HTML(s)
htmltable = htmlpage.xpath("//td//text()")
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
import urllib

budgeturl = "http://www.the-numbers.com/movie/budgets/all"
s = urllib.urlopen(budgeturl).read()

def find_between( s, first, last ):
    try:
        start = s.index( first ) + len( first )
        end = s.index( last, start )
        return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        return ""

s = find_between(s, '<table>', '</table>')

print s[:500]
print '.............................................................'
print s[-250:]
```

[Find string between two substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368969/find-string-between-two-substrings)

returns:

```
>>>
<tr><th>&nbsp;</th><th>Release Date</th><th>Movie</th><th>Production Budget</th><th>Domestic Gross</th><th>Worldwide Gross</th></tr>
<tr><td class="data">1</td>
<td><a href="/box-office-chart/daily/2009/12/18">12/18/2009</a></td>
<td><b><a href="/movie/Avatar#tab=summary">Avatar</a></td>
<td class="data">$425,000,000</td>
<td class="data">$760,507,625</td>
<td class="data">$2,783,918,982</td>
<tr>
<tr><td class="data">2</td>
<td><a href="/box-office-chart/daily/2015/12/18">12/18/2015</a></td>
.............................................................
</td>
<td><a href="/box-office-chart/daily/2005/08/05">8/5/2005</a></td>
<td><b><a href="/movie/My-Date-With-Drew#tab=summary">My Date With Drew</a></td>
<td class="data">$1,100</td>
<td class="data">$181,041</td>
<td class="data">$181,041</td>
<tr>
```

[image]

```
.........................................
```

[image]

> I need the text not the link.

via http://www.convertcsv.com/html-table-to-csv.htm

```
Release Date,Movie,Production Budget,Domestic Gross,Worldwide Gross
1,12/18/2009,Avatar,"$425,000,000","$760,507,625","$2,783,918,982"
8/5/2005,My Date With Drew,"$1,100","$181,041","$181,041"
```

you can use beautifulsoup to do the same, see:

[beautifulSoup html csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167352/beautifulsoup-html-csv)